# Generators don't work in Rails engine folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, generator, rails-engines

I have an app that's using multiple engines, following the [RailsGuides guidelines](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html). The engine works fine in my app, but the docs indicate that generators should work just fine from within the engine, and I can't get mine to work. When I try to run a generator, it says `command not found: rails`.

Here are the contents of `bin/rails` inside my engine's directory:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# This command will automatically be run when you run "rails" with Rails 4 gems installed from the root of your application.

ENGINE_ROOT = File.expand_path('../..', __FILE__)
ENGINE_PATH = File.expand_path('../../lib/my_engine/engine', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

require 'rails/engine/commands'
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: I have the same rails file but in a directory called scripts instead of bin; and all the generators work fine.

Comment: How did the file get into the engine's scripts directory? My engines don't even have these directories. They all have bin/rails and in each case they were auto generated.

Comment: No idea. But they work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was stupidly simple. I'd never run a `bundle install` in my engine folder. You'd think me a newb.

Answer (score 0):

I had to run `bundle install` and then `bundle exec`after having the same problem